# Video buffering/streaming with node-fluent-ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, video-streaming, buffer, fluent-ffmpeg

I want to turn AC3-audio videos playable on browsers. For this, I decided to use fluent-ffmpeg to real-time convert the videos and stream them. It works as livestreaming/piping pretty well, but you can't even go back in the videos.

```js
app.get('/video', function (req, res) {
  var path = 'show.mkv';
  ffmpeg(path)
    .outputOptions(arr)
    .on('end', function () {
      console.log('file has been converted succesfully');
    })
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('an error happened: ' + err.message);
    })
    .pipe(res);
});
```

So I need to build a sort of buffer for the conversion, this is, to let the user go back and forth in the video. I've found some code that does exactly what I need, although it doesn't convert:

```js
app.get('/video', function(req, res) {
  const path = 'assets/sample.mp4'
  const stat = fs.statSync(path)
  const fileSize = stat.size
  const range = req.headers.range

  if (range) {
    const parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-")
    const start = parseInt(parts[0], 10)
    const end = parts[1]
      ? parseInt(parts[1], 10)
      : fileSize-1

    const chunksize = (end-start)+1
    const file = fs.createReadStream(path, {start, end})
    const head = {
      'Content-Range': `bytes ${start}-${end}/${fileSize}`,
      'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
      'Content-Length': chunksize,
      'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
    }

    res.writeHead(206, head)
    file.pipe(res)
  } else {
    const head = {
      'Content-Length': fileSize,
      'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
    }
    res.writeHead(200, head)
    fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res)
  }
})
```

(from https://github.com/daspinola/video-stream-sample)

I've been trying to make fluent-ffmpeg work with buffering, with no success, and I pretty much have no clue on what to do. If buffering isn't possible, is there an similar alternative excpect for pre-converting the videos? Thanks already.